# Window painting problem

Tags: nvidia, graphics, window

I'm having trouble with some applications like built-in calculator, gEdit, blueFish editor. Parts of the application window are "transparent", it seems like a re-painting problem.

Changing the graphic card driver (nVidia GeForce GTX 770 - 384.111) to **xorg** does not correct the problem.

Here is a screenshot of the bug: [image]